# What's the quickest way to assemble in Photoshop printed pages of reference clipped from the screen?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I don't always have my laptop with me so I'd like to have several reference pages of textures stuck in my sketchbook.

What's the quickest way in Photoshop to assemble pages of reference  that I've clipped from the screen?  Pasting the pages into Photoshop for now takes a lot of tedious resizing and dragging.  It would be great to have some sort of template so that I could practically drag and drop.

This is Windows 10, so we're in Ctrl-C Ctrl-V territory.  And I'm a cheapskate so it's Photoshop CS 4 Extended.

Comment: I think CS4 still had  `File > Automate >  Contact Sheet`?

Comment: I had to download the plugin but that worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Contact Sheet is deigned to print thumbnails of a photo library.

Check `File > Automate > Contact Sheet` (Or Contact Sheet II)

You may need to download the Contact Sheet plug in for older Photoshop versions.

- Windows: https://supportdownloads.adobe.com/product.jsp?product=39&platform=Windows
- Mac: https://supportdownloads.adobe.com/product.jsp?product=39&platform=Macintosh

And in *some* versions, Adobe Moved the Contact Sheet to Bridge. So if you don't see it in Photoshop, look for it in Bridge.